# Display image content from Database into Telerik reporting

Tags: c#, telerik-reporting

I have an image stored in database and need to display in Telerik reporting to generate PDF. Is there any telerik reporing control available to parse these image into report viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PictureBox class](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/t_telerik_reporting_picturebox.html) is used for adding images to a report. You will have to implement the functionality for pulling the image from the database and assigning it to an instance of the PictureBox class yourself.